# Self Adjoint Operators

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inner-products, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

I was wondering if someone could give me a few examples of some self adjoint operators, I understand this topic in terms of matrices with inner product spaces. However I have seen integrals that are inner products and I don't know any examples for the inner product space on an integral?

Could someone give me an example of a self adjoint operator and non self adjoint operator on the integral inner product space please! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Let $K\colon [0,1]\times [0,1] \to \Bbb C$ be a continuous function and define $T_K\colon \mathcal{C}([0,1], \Bbb C) \to \mathcal{C}([0,1], \Bbb C)$ by $$T_K(f)(s) = \int_0^1 K(t,s) f(t)\,{\rm d}t.$$Assume that the inner product in $\mathcal{C}([0,1], \Bbb C)$ is given by $$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^1 f(s) \overline{g(s)}\,{\rm d}s.$$If $K$ satisfies the Hermitian symmetry $K(s,t) = \overline{K(t,s)}$, then $T_K$ is self-adjoint. Because $$\langle T_K(f),g\rangle = \int_0^1 T_K(f)(s)\overline{g(s)}\,{\rm d}s = \int_0^1\int_0^1 K(t,s)f(t)\overline{g(s)}\,{\rm d}t\,{\rm d}s,$$as well as $$\langle f, T_K(g)\rangle = \int_0^1 f(s) \overline{T_K(g)(s)}\,{\rm d}s = \int_0^1\int_0^1 f(s) \overline{K(t,s) g(t)}\,{\rm d}t\,{\rm d}s. $$Using the Hermitian symmetry of $K$ and renaming $t \leftrightarrow s$ if needed, we have $\langle T_K(f),g\rangle = \langle f,T_K(g)\rangle$. For a non self-adjoint operator, take $T_K$ where $K$ does *not* satisfy that Hermitian symmetry.

Comment: Could you give an example of such f, g, K etc just for clarity sake? Thank you though!

Comment: Sure, compute both integrals with $K \equiv 1$ and $f(t)=g(t)=t$ to get a feeling for what happens, it's easy enough.

Comment: Sorry another question! When would K not satisfy hermitian symmetry?

Comment: Try to write any example, it will probably fail. Like $K(t,s)=1+{\rm i}s$, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much